# How to disable Transparent Huge Pages (THP) in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am setting up an ambari cluster with 3 virtualbox VMs running Ubuntu 16.04LTS. However I get the below warning:

```
The following hosts have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) enabled. 
THP should be disabled to avoid potential Hadoop performance issues.
```

How can I disable THP in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you try this command:

```
sudo su
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

?

Alternatively, you may install [hugepages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/hugeadm.8.html)

```
sudo su
apt-get install hugepages
hugeadm --thp-never
```

As mentioned by [@Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650322/anthony), the effect would **not** persist after a reboot. Use your distribution-specific method to do that every time after reboot.

Comment: `hugepages` command did not work for me. 
I had to use `hugeadm`

Comment: Please correct the part regarding hubepages, the command should be:
`hugeadm --thp-never`

Answer (score 15):

Install :

`sudo apt install hugepages`

Then run :

`sudo hugeadm --thp-never`

To persist the changes you can add this last command to /etc/rc.local

Answer (score 15):

To disable Transparent Huge Pages (THP)  *permanently* choose **one** of the following options:

1. Via GRUB options (preferred):

   Edit `/etc/default/grub` to add `transparent_hugepage=never` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` option:

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="transparent_hugepage=never quiet splash"
   ```

After that, run `update-grub` command. (Need reboot to take effect)

2. With rc.local:

Edit `/etc/rc.local` and put following script before `exit 0`

```
    if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
       echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
    fi
```

* To avoid reboot (as mentioned before), you can disable it by `# echo never >  /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` command.

Comment:  might be worth being more clear that you only need to do either #1 or #2 and not both

Answer (score 9):

Below 3 commands fix the issue over Ubuntu(14.x/16.x) and also make it persistent on system boots.

1. `sudo apt-get install hugepages`
2. `sudo hugeadm --thp-never`
3. `sudo /bin/sed -i '$i /usr/bin/hugeadm --thp-never' /etc/rc.local`

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` contains `exit 0` as last line in my case. All scripts should be added before `exit`. Use `sed` command instead `sudo sed -i '$i hugeadm --thp-never' /etc/rc.local`. It will insert line before the last one.

Answer (score 7):

All of these answers are out of date. Tried all of them, and the values keep getting overwritten.

The guide here actually works: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/

It needs to be a service that runs at startup properly, just follow this guide

Worked on Ubuntu 19.04, finally suppressed the redis warnings

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 as well. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm this works on Ubuntu 20.04 as well. I just replaced mongod.service by redis.service in the systemd config.