# Memory allocation is too slow

Tags: memory, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, huge-pages

I am running some memory intensive service on AWS (`m4.15xlarge` and `m5.12xlarge` instances) and have noticed that in certain conditions (usually after a certain memory limit) the time it takes to allocate additional memory increases dramatically (up to 50x times).

When it is happening `htop` shows 100% in kernel mode (red) and `perf top` looks like this:

```
  62.82%  [kernel]                                           [k] pageblock_pfn_to_page                                                              
  15.21%  [kernel]                                           [k] clear_page_c_e                                                                     
   5.78%  [kernel]                                           [k] get_pfnblock_flags_mask                                                            
   3.06%  [kernel]                                           [k] compaction_alloc                                                                   
   1.59%  [kernel]                                           [k] clear_huge_page                                                                    
   1.49%  [kernel]                                           [k] _raw_spin_lock                                                                     
   1.41%  [kernel]                                           [k] async_page_fault                                                                   
   1.29%  a.out                                              [.] memTest                                                                            
   0.99%  [kernel]                                           [k] get_page_from_freelist                                                             
   0.85%  [kernel]                                           [k] compact_zone                                                                       
   0.69%  [kernel]                                           [k] try_charge                                                                         
   0.51%  [kernel]                                           [k] error_entry                                                                        
...
```

During normal operation it looks like this:

```
  66.29%  [kernel]                                           [k] clear_page_c_e
   7.05%  [kernel]                                           [k] clear_huge_page
   3.91%  a.out                                              [.] memTest
   3.66%  [kernel]                                           [k] _raw_spin_lock
   3.12%  [kernel]                                           [k] async_page_fault
   2.68%  [kernel]                                           [k] get_page_from_freelist
   1.93%  [kernel]                                           [k] _cond_resched
   1.49%  [kernel]                                           [k] try_charge
   1.12%  [kernel]                                           [k] error_entry
   1.01%  [kernel]                                           [k] retint_user
   0.93%  [kernel]                                           [k] handle_mm_fault
   0.77%  [kernel]                                           [k] mem_cgroup_try_charge
   0.67%  [kernel]                                           [k] pmd_pfn
   0.66%  [kernel]                                           [k] __rmqueue.isra.80
...
```

I am not entirely understand what is triggering the behavior. Sometime it is rather hard to reproduce but sometimes it is happening all the time.

*I have a hypothesis that this is related to AWS virtualization (so the fact that the issue is intermittent I attribute to what is happening on the "neighbors")* (see **Update** below). I also was unable to reproduce the problem on `m5.metal` machine.

I was able to reproduce the problem using a simple C program that allocates and initializes memory in a loop:

```c
void memTest(long chunk, long total) {
    struct timeval prev, cur = {0,0}, lastProgress = {0,0};
    int i, j;
    int num = total / chunk;
    int p, progress = -1;
    uint8_t *data[num];

    get_now(&prev);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        data[i] = malloc(chunk);
        for (j = 0; j < chunk; j += 4096) {
            data[i][j] = rand()%265;
        }

        get_now(&cur);
        add(delta(&prev, &cur));
        prev = cur;

        p = (i * 20) / num * 5;

        if (p != progress) {
            if (lastProgress.tv_sec == 0) {
                printf("%s: %02d%%\n", format(&cur), p);
            } else {
                double elapsed = delta(&lastProgress, &cur);
                printf("%s: %02d%% (%gms)\n", format(&cur), p, elapsed);
            }
            lastProgress = cur;
            progress = p;
        }
    }
}
```

```sh
m5.12xlarge$ ./a.out --total 182714368000 --chunk 16777216
2019-03-27 05:03:22.805827: 00%
2019-03-27 05:03:25.035575: 05% (2229.75ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:27.244955: 10% (2209.38ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:29.458160: 15% (2213.2ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:31.665313: 20% (2207.15ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:33.871949: 25% (2206.64ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:36.075955: 30% (2204.01ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:38.284512: 35% (2208.56ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:40.489039: 40% (2204.53ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:42.697444: 45% (2208.41ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:44.902268: 50% (2204.82ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:47.110703: 55% (2208.43ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:49.315001: 60% (2204.3ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:51.523370: 65% (2208.37ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:53.728535: 70% (2205.16ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:55.936081: 75% (2207.55ms)
2019-03-27 05:03:58.141149: 80% (2205.07ms)
2019-03-27 05:04:00.349740: 85% (2208.59ms)
2019-03-27 05:04:02.553894: 90% (2204.15ms)
2019-03-27 05:04:04.762675: 95% (2208.78ms)
2019-03-27 05:04:41.470692: 100% (36708ms) .  <---
```

This time I was only able to get the problem close to the memory limit, but I was able to get it even on 20Gb (out of 186Gb available).

I would greatly appreciate if someone could shade light on what is going on and how to get rid of this effect.

**Update:**

I have played with the issue a bit more and currently blaming Transparent Hugepage Support (THP) that happen to be enabled (`always`) on `m5.12xlarge` and disabled (`madvise`) on `m5.metal`. After toggling the setting on the machines I was able to get the issue on `m5.metal` and problem went away on `m5.12xlarge`.

Comment: Amazon EC2 instances are isolated from "neighbours". Memory is not oversubscribed, so "neighbours" will never impact CPU, Memory or disk access.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I think you are right and my hypothesis is wrong. I have played at bit more and it looks like the issue is caused by [Transparent Hugepage Support](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/transhuge.txt). I have checked that this feature was enabled on `m5.12xlarge` and disbaled `m5.metal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is suggested in **Update** section, the issue seems to be caused by  Transparent Huge Page ([THP](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/transhuge.txt)) support. It already has been found problematics by [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/) and some others [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99154/disable-transparent-hugepages), [link](https://redis.io/topics/latency) and recommended for disabling.

There are numerous questions on how to disable THP on stackoverflow and stackexchange. For example:

- [How to disable Transparent Huge Pages (THP) in Ubuntu 16.04LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800633/how-to-disable-transparent-huge-pages-thp-in-ubuntu-16-04lts)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99154/disable-transparent-hugepages
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209253/how-to-disable-transparent-huge-pages-in-centos6-6