# env: cmd: No such file or directory while launch spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, bigdata

I update the intellij to the latest version (2021.01) and while debugging my application whit a submit in spark i get this error:

env: cmd: No such file or directory

The spark submit is this:

[Spark submit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI77x.png)

I try launch the jar in my remote cluster.

The IDE upload the jar correctly bu the lauch throw this error.

Someone have this error?

Thanks :D

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like the error has something to do with transparent huge pages. see this post and check if you can disable that . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800633/how-to-disable-transparent-huge-pages-thp-in-ubuntu-16-04lts

Comment: I think this is not the problem, because i launch the spark-submit in the console of the cluster and its working.